# Executor service in a thread spawned by another executor service

Tags: java, multithreading

Have been facing trouble with the right usage of executor service. I am a new bee to executor and tried lot over web to resolve this. But couldn't justify it more.
i will try to put down my requirement and implementation done.

1. I have an infinite loop to spawn the threads and the maximum limit any time should be 50.

   ```
   public void createWorkers(){

       ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

       while(true) {
           executor.execute(innerRunnableThread); // a runnable thread
       }

   }
   ```

QUERY : since it's an infinite loop, how to shut down the executor service (executor.shutdown()) ?

2. "innerRunnableThread" mentioned in the first point has the below code :

   ```
   public class InnerRunnableThread implements Runnable {

       @Override
       public void run() {

           ExecutorService innerExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

           for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
               executor.execute(detailRunnableThread); // a runnable thread
           }
           innerExecutor.shutdown();
           try {
               innerExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               loggr.error("exception thrown while spawning threads");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

QUERY :
1. Parent thread ( in the 1st point), limit given as 50 threads. But with this implementation, parent threads not spawned more than 5. What is the reason for it ?

COMBINED QUERY :

With this approach, excluding shut down of the executor service in first point, there were thousands of threads lying un-terminated at the server. Finally leading to shutdown of this application and couldn't start any more ?

Kind help on this particular approach will be very helpful along with the better alternatives to achieve this logic.

Thanks alot.

Comment: 50 is a **massive** amount of threads to put in an executor service.

Comment: what could be the limit of number of threads in executor service ? any other suggestions on the code snippet ?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with it.

Comment: Admittedly, I hardly see a point in using 50 Threads just to start 50*10 threads, where each outer one has to bootstrap and shutdown an ExecutorService. If you want to manage "batches" of jobs, you could consider passing a List of Callables to the `invokeAll` method of a single ExecutorService. If the question is *only* about why only 5 of the parent threads have been used, I'd give it a try and have a closer look at this, maybe with a dedicated test where the "inner" threads are doing nothing than a fixed-time `sleep`...

Comment: Thanks Marco...initial 50 threads has to do a similar job and each of it's result has to pass it to another bunch of jobs.these bunch of jobs are designed as 10 threads. That is the reason inner executor service limited as 10 thread for each parent thread from 50.